# How to store values retrieved from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following is the part of the JSON

```
savedQuestionOptionsList: [
{
id: 3,
oid: {
id: 1,
name: "Excellent",
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
cqid: {
id: 19,
pqid: {
id: 9,
qid: {
id: 2,
category: "default",
question: "Staff Response",
cid: null,
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
pid: {
id: 2,
category: "default",
name: "Food And Beverage",
cid: null,
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
qtid: {
id: 4,
name: "option",
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
cid: {
id: 1,
name: "Taj",
createdDate: {
minimalDaysInFirstWeek: 1,
time: {
time: 1402030754000,
minutes: 29,
seconds: 14,
hours: 10,
month: 5,
timezoneOffset: -330,
year: 114,
day: 5,
date: 6
},
weekYear: 2014,
weeksInWeekYear: 52,
gregorianChange: {
time: -12219292800000,
minutes: 30,
seconds: 0,
hours: 5,
month: 9,
timezoneOffset: -330,
year: -318,
day: 5,
date: 15
},
timeZone: {
lastRuleInstance: null,
DSTSavings: 0,
rawOffset: 19800000,
ID: "Asia/Calcutta",
dirty: false,
displayName: "India Standard Time"
},
lenient: true,
timeInMillis: 1402030754000,
firstDayOfWeek: 1,
weekDateSupported: true
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
{
id: 4,
oid: {
id: 4,
name: "Poor",
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
cqid: {
id: 20,
pqid: {
id: 9,
qid: {
id: 2,
category: "default",
question: "Staff Response",
cid: null,
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
pid: {
id: 2,
category: "default",
name: "Food And Beverage",
cid: null,
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
qtid: {
id: 4,
name: "option",
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
cid: {
id: 1,
name: "Taj",
createdDate: {
minimalDaysInFirstWeek: 1,
time: {
time: 1402030754000,
minutes: 29,
seconds: 14,
hours: 10,
month: 5,
timezoneOffset: -330,
year: 114,
day: 5,
date: 6
},
weekYear: 2014,
weeksInWeekYear: 52,
gregorianChange: {
time: -12219292800000,
minutes: 30,
seconds: 0,
hours: 5,
month: 9,
timezoneOffset: -330,
year: -318,
day: 5,
date: 15
},
timeZone: {
lastRuleInstance: null,
DSTSavings: 0,
rawOffset: 19800000,
ID: "Asia/Calcutta",
dirty: false,
displayName: "India Standard Time"
},
lenient: true,
timeInMillis: 1402030754000,
firstDayOfWeek: 1,
weekDateSupported: true
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
},
deleted: false,
version: 0
}
],
```

To retrieve it I am using following jquery way

```
 $.each(data1.savedQuestionOptionsList, function(index, currQueOpt) {
                    console.log(currQueOpt.oid.id +"cqid id "+currQueOpt.cqid.id);
```

I have a table tr

```
<tr>
   <td><input id="checked2" type="checkbox" class="cd" value="2" style="margin:6px 0 0 0;"></td>
   <td style="padding:6px 0 0 0;"><b>Staff Response</b></td>
   <td>
      <select name="questionType" id="questionType" class="qType QSelect" style="padding:3px;">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
         <option value="1">text</option>
         <option value="2">rating</option>
         <option value="3">boolean</option>
         <option class="show-checkboxes" value="4">option</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td width="35%" style="padding:10px 0 0 0;" class="Fsize12 out" id="a2"><a href="#" class="checkbox-inline" onclick="getModal(this)">Get Options</a></td>
   <td><input type="hidden" id="optionInputa2"></td>
</tr>
```

Now my requirement is to append the value of oid.name(in the given JSON oid.name gives 2 values excellent and poor and both have pqid.qid.id value as 2) to above `td` whose class is out.

I can do like this

```
$.each(data1.savedQuestionOptionsList, function(index, currQueOpt) {
                    console.log(currQueOpt.oid.id +"cqid id "+currQueOpt.cqid.id);

                    $('#checked'+currQueOpt.cqid.pqid.qid.id).closest('tr').find('.out').html     (currQueOpt.oid.name);
```

But I have to do some process before appending so I can not use directly inside each function.Is there any way to store qid.id and oid.name and after that I can loop and append

Comment: full json can be found [here](http://pastie.org/9276433)

Comment: The first piece of code may be JS, but it's not JSON (as keys must be between `"`) Is that code copied from the debugger once it has been stored?

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, create another block of HTML with attribute: `style="display: none"` and to mark all inside elements with IDs, append parsed JSON values there and then select and proccess it with jQuery.

Also, inside `$.each` statement you could call some callback function, which will first proccess your data and then append it where it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for answering,Unfortuantely  I can not do your way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you need, but here are my two cents: I think the easiest way is just create an auxiliar variable and store there what you want:

```
var aux=[];

$.each(data1.savedQuestionOptionsList, function(index, currQueOpt) {
        console.log(currQueOpt.oid.id +"cqid id "+currQueOpt.cqid.id);
        aux.push({name: currQueOpt.oid.name, id:currQueOpt.cqid.pqid.qid.id});
    }
);
```

Then you can process those values:

```
for (var i=0;i< aux.length;i++) {
    //process aux[i].id
    //process aux[i].name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.pqid.qid.id is nothing but the row id.So i have to put the value of currQueOpt.oid.name in the row(pqid.qid.id)In the above json qid is repeated

Comment: I just put those values as an example, you can store in aux what you need.

Comment: can you come to chat room so that we can discuss about this in more detail http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-spring-jsf-struts-hibernate-php-jquery-javascript-beginners